# React Native iOS TextInput: switching secureTextEntry switches font

Tags: ios, react-native

I want to implement show password feature in TextInput in React Native `0.30.0`. I've implemented 'eye' button next to TextInput which change state of `passwordHidden` state variable. Here is my code:

```
...
  <View style={[styles.passwordWrapper, styles.textInputBorder]}>
        <TextInput
          autoCapitalize={'none'}
          autoCorrect={false}
          clearButtonMode={'while-editing'}
          style={[styles.textInput, styles.passwordInput]}
          onChangeText={(password) => this.onPasswordChange(password)}
          value={this.state.password}
          secureTextEntry={this.state.passwordHidden}
          multiline={false}
          placeholder={Strings.password}
          underlineColorAndroid={Colors.surfacePrimary}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.showPasswordButton} onPress={this.onPressShowPassword}>
          <EntypoIcon color={Colors.surfacePrimary} name={this.state.passwordHidden ? 'eye' : 'eye-with-line'} size={20} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
...
onPressShowPassword: function () {
    var previousState = this.state.passwordHidden;
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        this.setState({
             passwordHidden: !previousState,
        });
    });
},
```

Here's how password `TextInput` looks before clicking on button.
[image]
And after clicking:
[image]
And when I tap third time and start type then password is immediately cleared. I am not changing fontFamily in styles even in entire app.

**Anybody can explain what is going on? Or just how to overcome that annoying behavior.**

Comment: I have ran into this before. This is an open React Native bug - although the issue appears to have been closed prematurely: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5859

Comment: In addition, the value being cleared seems to have been reported as well https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9148

Answer (score 2):

Workaround that is working for me, is removing focus from TextInput, when user clicks show/hide password. One way to do this, is to add ref (for example `ref="password"`) to your TextInput and then call `this.refs.password.blur()`

Answer (score 1):

changing the fontSize works for me:

```
fontSize: (this.state.showPassword) ? 24 : 23
```